# Big Query PROBLEM in MERGE when the source table has multiple lines for the table keys

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working on a project to merge data from a source table (zsource) to target table (ztarget). The Target table is as shown below

**ztarget**:-

```
a,b,n
a1,b1,10
a2,b2,15
```

The source table we get comes from a tool which captures database triggers and sends the data as a delta records. In the table below DI_SEQUENCE_NUMBER is the sequence in which the DB operation takes place and DI_OPERATION_TYPE is the type of operation with (D=delete, U=update, I=insert) .

**zsource** :-

```
DI_SEQUENCE_NUMBER,DI_OPERATION_TYPE,a,b,n
0,U,a1,b1,15
1,U,a1,b1,16
2,D,a1,b1,33
3,I,a1,b1,43
4,U,a1,b1,55
5,U,a1,b1,65
0,U,a2,b2,99
```

How can I merge the data from the source table(zsource) to the target table(ztarget) in the exact sequence in the source table . I tried the below Merge statement but it is giving me the error **"UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row"**

```
MERGE zsac_figl01.ztarget T
USING (SELECT * FROM `sap01-188316.zsac_figl01.zsource` ORDER BY DI_SEQUENCE_NUMBER) S
ON 
T.a = S.a and
T.b = S.b 

WHEN MATCHED AND S.DI_OPERATION_TYPE = 'U' THEN
  UPDATE SET 
T.a = S.a,
T.b = S.b
WHEN MATCHED AND S.DI_OPERATION_TYPE = 'D' THEN
  DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT 
  (a,b ) 
VALUES
  (a,b )
```

Comment: According to the documentation, this error happens " If a row in the table to be updated joins with more than one row from the FROM clause, then the query generates the following runtime error". It is also suggested that you use UPDATE JOINS, I am currently checking if it is possible to use it with your case. Link:https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through the documentation, I found out that ( as I stated in the comment section):

> If a row in the table to be updated joins with more than one row from the FROM 
>   clause, then the query generates the following runtime error: UPDATE/MERGE must 
>   match at most one source row for each target row.

Meaning that you can have at most one match in the **TARGET TABLE** from each row in the **SOURCE TABLE**. In your case, you have actions which would have to occur in the same row. In other words, for the same pair of **a** and **b**  in the **TARGET TABLE** , you have more than one match in the **SOURCE TABLE**. This can not happen when using [MERGE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_examples).

Notwithstanding, there is a work around your issue. You aim to perform one action at a time, however note that if you perform only the last action you would get the same output. Thus, you could change your [source table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement), located at your ***USING*** statement, to execute only the last action/modification ordered by ***DI_SEQUENCE_NUMBER***.

Your USING statement you look like:

```
USING ( SELECT s1.* from `zsource` s1 
      inner join (select MAX(DI_SEQUENCE_NUMBER) as DI_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_MAX, a, b 
                    FROM `zsource` group by a,b
                 ) s2 on s1.a=s2.a and 
                   s1.b=s2.b and 
                   s2.DI_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_MAX = s1.DI_SEQUENCE_NUMBER) S
```

I would like to point that the output from the [INNER JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#inner-join) performed is:

[image]

That means you would be considering only the last actions based on *DI_SEQUENCE_NUMBER*.

In addition, I want to acknowledge your use of **UPDATE** and **INSERT**. I believe you should add the field **n**, otherwise you won't change any of your data since *a1=a1* and *b1=b1*. Below is the syntax:

```
WHEN MATCHED AND S.DI_OPERATION_TYPE = 'U' THEN
UPDATE SET 
T.a = S.a,
T.b = S.b,
T.n = S.n
WHEN MATCHED AND S.DI_OPERATION_TYPE = 'D' THEN
  DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT 
  (a,b,n) 
VALUES
  (a,b,n)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: this is exactly what was needed . Great !!